# Play framework bind from request constructor

Tags: playframework-2.1

I'm having trouble when binding data from form, my User class has a constructor which hashes the password, the problem is that if I get the user from the form the password is stored as plain text.

My User constructor:

```
 public User(String username, String completeName, String password,
        String email) {
    this.username = username.toLowerCase();
    this.email = email;
    this.registrationDate = new Date();
    this.completeName = completeName;
    try {
        String[] passAndSalt = PasswordHash.createHash(password).split(":");
        this.salt = passAndSalt[0];
        this.password = passAndSalt[1];
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public static Result addUser() {
    Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (!userForm.hasErrors()) {
        User formUser = userForm.get();
        formUser.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    } else {
        return badRequest(registerUser.render(userForm));
    }
}
```

I could hash the password before saving the user, but I was wondering if there is a way for Play to use the constructor I defined.

Using Play! version 2.1.1

Comment: Do you use `private` field values with getters and setter in your model? If not, that could be the problem. Play uses Jackson http://jackson.codehaus.org/DataBindingDeepDive to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: @ricard.m.o my fields are all public. I found in the play [doc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.2/model#anamepropertiesPropertiessimulationa) that play generates getters and setters at runtime and that fields should be left public. And that if I define the setters play will use them. I will try defining the setters

Comment: In order to generate getters and setters, Play has to do bytecode enhancement. I remember having a similar issue and think that when doing so, it will resort to the default empty constructor. Using getters and setters fixed the problems we had.